# Cypress click on html5 video buttons (play/pause, mute, scroll video, fullscreen)

Tags: cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I am trying to click on the options like play/pause, mute, fullscreen etc on an html5 video element. But the problem is these are not available in the DOM for me to select the element. I tried to do click using coordinates but it is not working. Also cypress do not support keyboard actions else I could have used Tab and spacebar to perform the actions. Can someone please suggest a solution to perform the actions on an html5 video element?

Sample html5 video

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

Answer (score 0):

For mute and play you can use this:

```js
it('html5 video', () => {
    cy.visit("https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp");
    cy.get('#accept-choices').click();
    cy.get('#video1').then((video) => {
      const element = video.get(0);
      element.muted = true;
      element.play();
      return video;
    })
  });
```

The `return video` it's optional.